# ASP.NET Core Route Tag Helper use Route?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I'm kind off confused about how the asp-route-* tag helper works. What I understand is that it's kind of bound to the routing I've setup. E.g.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
    name: null,
    template: "{category}/Page{page:int}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "List" }
 );
```

Here I map my route as follow: /Category/PageNumber for the Action "List" in Controller "Product"

The following code will, when clicked follow the previous maproute

```
<a class="btn btn-block 
   @(cat == ViewBag.SelectedCategory ? "btn-primary" : "btn-default")"
    asp-controller="Product"
    asp-action="List"
    asp-route-category="@cat"
    asp-route-page="1">@cat</a>
```

So how I understand it is that "asp-route-category" will search for "{category}" in my routeMap template, and then "asp-route-page" will search for "{page}" in the routeMap template ?

The documentation on MS is kind off confusing or just to abstract, can someone confirm or explain this in a better way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using [conventional routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing), as you are doing, the `controller` and `action` parameters are required and map to your controller and action name.

So if you want to route to the Action `List` in Controller `Product` with a 
Category and a Page parameter, your routing should be like the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: null,
    template: "{controller}/{action}/{category}/Page{page:int}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "List" }
 );
```

**Update:**

The `asp-route` attribute in the [Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro) you are using, will provide parameters to route values.

So basically, `asp-route-MyParameter` will add `MyParameter` to route values with the specified value.

[More Information here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms).

Comment: That part is very clear, I'm more confused about the "asp-route-x" part. The "x" can be anything, right ? But it must match with something of your map route ?